# "Failed to join all peers to channel. cause:Error: Invalid results returned ::FORBIDDEN"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have created Network with two organizations Org1 have two peers and org2 has one peer. After creating crypto-config and genisis block. I turn On the network. The network started successfully after that I have registered users of each organization which also succeed. After that I created a channel and org1 Join the channel successfully and when I join org2 to channel it gives

> "Failed to join all peers to channel. cause:Error: Invalid results returned ::FORBIDDEN"" Error.

This is my docker-compose.yaml file
[image]
This is my error
[image: error]
and this is an image of logs of peer0.cma.example.com
[image: peer logs]

Comment: Check your logs for peer0Org2: `docker container logs peer0.cma.example.com`. It start successfully? Or with errors?

Comment: @AlexanderYammine there is no error in logs

Comment: How are you joining the peer to the channel?